# How to merge laravel project git from colleague

Tags: laravel, github

I'm working on laravel project with git repository. I would like to merge code with my colleague. But I do not understand much for git merging.

For example: Below is current remote code.

```
class SettingTestTopicController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        return view('setting.testtopic.index');
    }
}
```

And below is my code

```
class SettingTestTopicController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        return view('setting.testtopic.index');
    }

    public function Create(){
        return view('setting.testtopic.create');
    }
}
```

And another is my colleague's code.

```
class SettingTestTopicController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        return view('setting.testtopic.index');
    }

    public function Edit($id){
        return view('setting.testtopic.edit');
    }
}
```

There're three different codes.If my colleague push code to git, so remote code will be like him. My need is, once I pull latest to my local. I would like to append like below.

```
class SettingTestTopicController extends Controller
{
    public function Index(){
        return view('setting.testtopic.index');
    }

    public function Create(){
        return view('setting.testtopic.create');
    }

    public function Edit($id){
        return view('setting.testtopic.edit');
    }
}
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you attempt to merge, Git will recognize the changes and attempt to automatically resolve conflicts. If it cannot automatically resolve them, git will create a modified version of the file that shows a preamble for the remote change and for your local changes, and allow you to edit them before continuing.

For example, from [this guide to resolving merge conflicts](https://help.github.com/en/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line):

```
If you have questions, please
<<<<<<< HEAD
open an issue
=======
ask your question in IRC.
>>>>>>> branch-a
```

Once you've saved the changes and they meet your standards, you can do `git add controller.php` (or the appropriate file name) and then `git commit -m "Merge Carol's edit feature with my Create feature"`.

If you like, you can run tests after making those changes but before making the merge commit.